# regex double number

Tags: .net, regex

here we go. i want to have regex for double number. but not only numbers separated with comma, i want to check, is it double? i mean in .net for double we have 64-bit only. how can i check it in regex?
and i dont want to do double.tryparse().

Comment: Ok, I'll ask. Why won't you use `TryParse`? And what do you mean by "separated with comma"? Is comma the decimal separator? 1/2 = 0,5, or do you have a list of numbers?

Comment: sorry, not comma, dot. i think one from all purposes of regex is to validate smth. why can not i validate numbers? for example: 3412634634764347343645374537883488478247 - is not integer in .net

Comment: So why would you use a regex? It's probably possible, but it [won't be pretty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc%28VS.71%29.aspx), and pretty pointless, since the framework already does that for you.

Comment: ok. thx. i will use tryparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex doesn't see numbers as a datatype**

It can only parse the text in front of it.  If you're looking for a number with a decimal point - then your regex will be checking for a number with a decimal point.

Parhaps you should rearrange your question to reflect this